# How to convert nvarchar type date into dd-mm-yyyy when the column contains mm-dd-yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: sql-server

I need to substract two dates for finding number of days. In the column of date I encounter 4 types of date format like 02-05-2020, in both MM-DD-YYYY, DD-MM-YYYY, also like 02-Aug-2020 or Aug-01-2020.

In SQL Server the convert function does not work where the issue is of interpreting 02-05-2020 as Feb 2 2020 or 02 May 2020.

How can one convert such dates from nvarchar type to uniform format in date type?

PS: SQL Server database.

Comment: You can't. If you can't tell what date `03-06-2020` is if you don't know the format, nor can sql server

Comment: Can you (as a person looking at the data) decide whether 02-05-2020 is the 2nd of May or the 5th of Feb? If you can't, how should SQL Server? If you can, what are the rules?

Comment: And there is one big reason for storing dates correctly as a date/dateime datatype.

Comment: Although you *could* always assume the values are in 1 format, and then only try the other(s) if that conversion fails, that is too, a terrible idea.  The only *real* solution, in my opinion, is to `TRUNCATE` the table, change the data type to a `date` and then re-`INSERT` all your data again. As you have no idea if a `02-05-2020` is May or February then the data is already useless and has lost any meaning, so getting the information from the original source is the only way to repair that.

Comment: Actually The Database we have inherited involves millions of data of land records , user does not fill the date so date inserted must be from the system . How four types of formats for the date got inserted ?

Comment: How could anyone not directly involved in that system design answer that question? Even you cannot - and you at least have some actual knowledge.